# How to show ui.combo popup manually?

Tags: javascript, combobox, popup, position, webix

I'm trying to open a popup of Webix combo control programmatically, but there are three issues I can't overcome.

Here's the [**snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/10fde508) that represents them:

- popup list spreads to the width of the form container (probably the current `combo.$view` is the wrong target to open a popup)

Only on initial state (I mean the popup wasn't opened yet by user actions)

- the initial value is ignored
- new value can't be selected from the opened popup

Here's the code of the combo and the button:

```
{ 
  view:"combo",
  inputWidth:350, 
  id:"mycombo", 
  value:1, 
  options:list_data
},
{ 
  view:"button",
  value:"show popup", 
  click:function(){ 
    var combo = $$("mycombo"); 
    var list = combo.getList();
    list.show( combo.$view ); // probably wrong
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (or is it possible at all). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! `list.show( combo.$view )` was really troublesome notation. In the following code

```
var combo = $$("mycombo"); 
var list = combo.getList();
list.show(combo.getInputNode());
```

**`show(combo.getInputNode())`** resolves two of three problems. Still, I have no idea how to make the *visual* selection work initially, but for now, it's not a big deal.